# two special functions

Tags: real-analysis

Can we find two functions $f:[0,1/2] \to [0,1/2]$ and $g:[1/2,1] \to [0,1/2]$ such that

1) $f$ is monotone increasing, but $g$ is monotone decreasing

2) $\int_0^{1/2} f(t) dt \geq \int_{1/2}^1 g(t) dt$

3) $\int_0^{1/2} f(t)(1-t) dt \leq \int_{1/2}^1 g(t)(1-t) dt$

Do such functions $f$ and $g$ exist? I've tried to show that they must exist but can't seem to find the right estimates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not exist.  The $1-t$ on the left in 3) is greater than $\frac 12$, while the one on the right is less than $\frac 12$  So from 2) we have $$\int_0^{1/2} f(t)(1-t) dt \geq \frac 12\int_0^{1/2} f(t) dt  \geq \frac 12\int_{1/2}^1 g(t) dt\geq \int_{1/2}^1 g(t)(1-t) dt$$ which contradicts 3) without using 1)